# Why use the two-argument form of the `iter` function instead of a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

I came across the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#iter) built-in function in python, which I had never seen used before. The "real-world" example it gives is reading through a large file:

> ```
> from functools import partial
> with open('mydata.db', 'rb') as f:
>     for block in iter(partial(f.read, 64), b''):
>         process_block(block)
> ```

However, it seems like the same effect can be used with a basic `while` loop without having to use the fancy functions (unless I'm mistaken) --

```
with open('mydata.db') as f:
    while True:
        block = f.read(50)
        if not block: break
        process_block(block)
```

What would be the advantage of using the `iter` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-argument version of `iter` is a convenience function that helps in writing more concise code. It has no functional advantage over the equivalent `while` loop that you included.

Comment: thanks. Are there other use cases where `iter` is used (it seems the example in the docs is a bit "forced").

Comment: I personally often use `list(iter(input, ''))` to let the user create a list by entering items until a blank line. It's quite a convenient shortcut. Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ToughGorgeousBlogs